# AutoHotKey (AHK) How to crop text in a Gui Button

Tags: button, user-interface, text, crop, autohotkey

How do I make a Gui Button that contains a set amount of rows, and when the variable displayed in it goes over that amount it will crop out the end and put "..." in it.
Currently I have this:

Gui, Add, Button, w200 r2 gbutton1, &1. %var1%

And when the amount of text in var1 goes over 2 rows worth of text, the button looks hideous. I need it to crop out the extra text in the button instead.

Comment: Obviously, you'll have to analyze, and if necessary manipulate `var1`. Have you tried that? Also, please format the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something along the lines of this:

```
var1 := "This text is too long."
Gui, Add, Button, w200 r2 , % "&1." . button(var1)
Gui, Add, Button, w200 r2 , % "&2." . button(var1, 15)
Gui, Show

button(var, maxlength = 7)
{
    if StrLen(var) > 10
        return % SubStr(var, 1, maxlength) . "..."
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes my GUIs a lot prittier, but now it is broken. The words are cropted, but the buttons now do nothing. This code doesn't work any more. button1: 
WinActivate [title]
Send %var1%
Gui Cancel
return

Comment: Be sure `gButton1` is in your code, as I removed it from my answer.